# CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0

Tags: python, macos, pygame

I'm trying to draw a simple system of lines, but when I try running the code in terminal (running OS X Lion) or DrPython I receive an error (CGContextRestoreGState: invalid context 0x0). I'm running python 2.7.

```
import pygame as pg
pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640,480))
l1 = 1.0 * L
l2 = 0.5377 * L
l3 = 0.2867 * L
hip = (100,100)
knee = (hip[0] + math.sqrt(2) * l1, hip[1] + math.sqrt(2) * l1)
ankle = (knee[0] + math.sqrt(2) * l2, knee[1] + math.sqrt(2) * l2)
toe = (ankle[0] + l3, ankle[1])
pg.draw.lines(screen, (0, 0, 0), False, [hip, knee, ankle, toe], 1)
while True:
for event in pg.event.get():
if event.type == pg.QUIT:
raise SystemExit
```

Answer (score 0):

Number of extra issues:

- What is "L"?  You probably edited it out.
- You need to call pygame.display.flip() inside your main loop, or you won't see anything.
- It is recommended that the list of tuples you pass to pygame.draw.lines be tuples of  *integers*.  Yours include tuples of floats.
- Indenting.  I'll assume it is correct in your original source.

Your main problem is that the context being created is invalid.  I assume this is occurring on the call to pygame.display.set_mode.  A quick Google search reveals that CGContextRestoreGState sets the context to NULL if an error occurred.  The answers you find there will help you fix the problem.

In particular, the key questions are, *where* (which line) does your error occur?  Do the PyGame samples work?